# Restaurar una base de datos de mysql en java

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo problemas al tratar de restaurar un respaldo de una base de datos en java... Tengo el código:

```
public boolean importar(String ruta){
    boolean bnd=false;
    String sentencia = rutaMySQL+"mysql -u "+user+" -p"+pass+" "+bd+" < "+ruta;
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        System.out.println(sentencia);
        rt.exec(sentencia);
        bnd = true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MySQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return bnd;
}
```

Esto no me funciona, si me devuelve el valor "true" pero no realiza la restauración. Lo raro es que el mismo comando me funciona perfectamente desde la CMD... Alguien sabe el error?

Comment: Al final de cuentas todo ha estado bien, el problema ha radicado en la PC del cliente ya que esta demora mucho más tiempo de lo que yo conocía al realizar la ejecución de los comandos. Solo le he asignado un tiempo mayor de espera a la ejecución y listo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**rt.exec(sentencia);** recuerda que al hacer eso toda la información se queda en memoria, es por eso que no ves reflejada tu backup.

Yo tuve un problema similar a ese, la explicacion te la paso linea por linea para que entiendas como funciona.

```
/*Este metodo recibira los siguientes parámetros.
 * @param host ruta de tu mysql
 * @param puert numero de puerto
 * @param  usuar
 * @param password
 * @param ruta aquí va la ruta donde deseas guardar tu backup
 * @param BD nombre de la base de datos
 */
public boolean importar(String host, String puert, String usuar, String password,String ruta,String BD){
 boolean ok=false;
    try{       
        //sentencia para crear el BackUp
         Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "cmd /c mysqldump --host=" + host + " --port=" + puert +
        " --user=" + usuar + " --password=" + password +
        " --complete-insert --extended-insert" +
        " " + ""+BD+"");
        //se guarda en memoria el backup
        InputStream in = run.getInputStream();
        //inicializamos para poder las lineas del backup
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        //para guardar los datos como string
        StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();
        int count;
        //hacemos una arreglo con una longitud apoximada de caracteres
        char[] cbuf = new char[10485760];
        //Empezamos a leer las líneas obtenidas
        while ((count = br.read(cbuf, 0, BUFFER)) != -1){
            //anexamos a nuestro buffer de string la línea leida
            //se agrega el arreglo obtenido y la longitud de este
            temp.append(cbuf, 0, count);
        }
        //cerramos los buffers
        br.close();
        in.close();        
        /* se crea y escribe el archivo SQL anexandole la ruta específica*/
        Archivo = new FileWriter(ruta);
        //para poder escribir sobre un fichero usaremos las clase PrintWriter
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Archivo);
        //escribimos el fichero añadiendo salto de línea                                                    
        pw.println(temp.toString());  
        ok=true;
   }
    catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       try {           
         if (null != Archivo)
             Archivo.close();
       } catch (Exception e2) {
           e2.printStackTrace();
       }
    }   
    return ok; 
 }
```

Comment: Probaré tu código muchas gracias por la ayuda y el tiempo!